# servicios en android

Tags: java, android

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en android que ejecuta un `servicio` en segundo plano , he estado probando con diferentes servicios y sucede que todos se me ejecutan bien mientras la app corre normalmente, **cuando cierro la aplicacion el servicio se detiene.** ¿Alguien sabe porque sucede esto?.

```
public class serviceMusic extends Service{
    private MediaPlayer med;
    private Timer mTimer = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        this.mTimer = new Timer();

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        med= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.uci);
        med.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        med.stop();
    }
}
```

logcat que genera cuando cierro la app

> 04-11 08:56:54.133 2263-2263/com.example.root.primera D/MediaPlayer:
>   handleMessage msg:(4, 0, 0) 04-11 08:57:11.352
>   2263-2263/com.example.root.primera D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches
>   (mode 0) 04-11 08:57:11.369 2263-2263/com.example.root.primera
>   D/ActivityThread: ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 /
>   android.os.BinderProxy@41e082d0 04-11 08:57:11.369 2263-2263/?
>   D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 /
>   ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@41e98f08 startId=2
>   args=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.example.root.primera/.MainActivity }}

Comment: Cual es el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat.

Comment: El @Override de `onStartCommand` esta bien. Si haces una depuración, recibes una excepción de la app?

Comment: no no recibo ninguna axcepción ,solo se cierra la aplicacion y el servicio

Comment: en el AndroidManifest.xml declaras el servicio?

Comment: ¿Has echado un vistazo a este ejemplo? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service Saludos!

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service Saludos!

Comment: he visto ese ejemplo y es paresido ,si he declarado el servicio en el manifes ,y me funciona ,se reproduce la cancion en seghundo plano , incluso si abro otra aplicacion y dejo corriendo la principal sigue ejecutandose ,pero cuando la cierro completamente si se cierra el servicio ,he visto varios ejemplos y videos de servicios de esto mismo de reproduccion de musica en segundo plano y les funciona sin embargo a mi no ,por lo menos completamente como me gustaria que funcionara ,que yo cierre la aplicacion y el se siga ejecutando hasta que yo decida pararlo, saludos y gracias por tus comentarios

Comment: @GerardoDíazRodríguez no es que se cierre la aplicación por un error el problema, el problema es que el servicio debería continuar ejecutando la reproducción del audio, agrego varias notas con respecto a tu código y agrego un ejemplo en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ejecutan bien mientras la app corre normalmente ,cuando cierro la
> aplicacion el servicio se detiene.

Hay varias cosas a comentar:

-Cuando se detiene el servicio se llama `onDestroy()`, te recomiendo validar si la instancia de MediaPlayer no es nula y además muy importante llamar `release()` después de `stop()`.

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(med != null){
           med.stop();
           med.release();
        }
    }
```

-No necesitas una instancia de `Timer`.

-`onStartCommand()` se usa para iniciar el servicio no para instanciar `MediaPlayer` , para esto se usa `onCreate()`. Muy importante, la constante `START_STICKY` debe tener el valor de 1 o usar `Service.START_STICKY` :

```
  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       /* med= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.uci);
        med.start();

        return START_STICKY;*/
      
        player.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

Por otro lado comentas que si cierras la aplicación el servicio se detiene, debes asegurar que no se este llamando:

```
 stopService(myService);
```

---

Agrego un ejemplo:

#### Servicio para reproducir en background (segundo plano) un audio almacenado en el directorio /raw.

```
package com.tototita.musicbackground;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


/* Add declaration of this service into the AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag*/

public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundSoundService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind()" );
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jorgesys_song);
        player.setLooping(true); 
        player.setVolume(100,100);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service started...");

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUnBind()");
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
    }
    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service stopped...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
    }
}
```

---

> Cierro la app y se para la reproducción pero vuelve a iniciar.

Esto es entendible, recuerda que se esta usando  `Service.START_STICKY`, revisa la documentación:

> **Service.START_STICKY** : recrea el servicio si la aplicación se destruye.
>
> **Service.START_NOT_STICKY** : El sistema operativo no recreara el servicio si la aplicación se destruye.

Comment: he provado tu ejemlpo exactamente como lo tienes y me hace lo mismo ,cundo cierro la aplicacion se me cierra ,realmente no se que are mal que me pasa esto pero por lo que veo no deve ser la implementacion del servicio , no se si ahiga que agregarle algo mas al  manifes o algo mas que tenga en la implementacion de la aplicacion principal que me afecte al sevicio , de todas forma tu respuestas estan muy bien gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Agrega lo que muestra en LogCat asegura tener permisos para conexión a internet que es lo ùnico que podrìa provocar un error. Si tienes más problemas te puedo compartir un ejemplo completo.

Comment: te agradeceria si me compartieras un ejemlo completopq la verdad que ya no se donde pueda estar el problema , cree un nuevo proyect desde cero nama para correr el servi y me pasa lo mismo

Comment: @GerardoDíazRodríguez con gusto : https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Music-in-Background.

Comment: ahora mira esto , prove la app en otro movil ese mismo ejemplo que me distes y si funciona ,cierro la app y se para la reproduccion pero vuelve a arancar sin estar la aplicacion corriendo .entonces esto deve ser algo con la compativilidad o alguna configuracion ,sabes que pueda ser?

Comment: es porque en el servicio se usa Service.START_STICKY : recrea el servicio si la aplicación se destruye.

Comment: asi lo tengo en el codico con el Service.START_STICKY, y funciona en otro movil y en un emulador tambien ,pero em mi movil se detiene , no se si mi version de android o el telefono tenga algo que ver con eso , mi android es 4.2.2 telef bluu,

Comment: Se detiene o se cierra porque sucede algún error, si es un error revisa el LogCat!

Comment: esto es lo que me muestran los logat:

Comment: este es un error que me lanza en los logcat  -04-10 21:34:31.689 9073-9073/com.example.gera.servicios E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.gera.servicios.MainActivity.access$super

Comment: el locat es muy largo para que me lo acepte por aki , si puedes darme un correo para mandarte un txt seria mejor

Comment: Agregalo en la pregunta principalmente donde dice "Caused by.."

Comment: ahi te agregue los logat que genberta cuando la cierro ,

Comment: creo que esto es lo que me destrulle el servicio lo que no se es por que ni como cambiarlo :

Comment: 04-11 09:17:49.443 6363-6363/com.example.root.primera D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@41ebf8b8 startId=2 args=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.root.primera/.MainActivity }}