# Como dejar un servicio funcionando en segundo plano en Android cerrando la aplicación que lo inicia

Tags: android, hilos, servicio, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Desde una aplicación para Android creo y ejecuto un servicio que corre en un hilo y se ejecuta en segundo plano, pero al cerrar por completo la aplicación principal también muere el servicio.

El hilo que creo lo declaro como Daemon pero aún así me "mata" el servicio.

Mi idea es dejar el servicio funcionando aunque cerremos la aplicación principal, un estilo wasap que cuando cierras el programa principal te siguen llegando los mensajes.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: echale un ojo a mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30116/crear-cron-en-android/30348#30348) en la que muestro cómo hacer un cron que se ejecute independientemente de si la app está arrancada o no, y se ejecutará cada X tiempo

Comment: WhatsApp y otras aplicaciones no funcionan en segundo plano para recibir mensajes (esto malgasta energía), utilizan un servicio que normalmente se conoce como "notificaciones push" que es básicamente un puerto abierto en el celular que siempre está escuchando y recibe las notificaciones de las distintas aplicaciones

Comment: @Joacer me robaste la idea de dejar tu respuesta jajaja!, Pablo, en la pregunta de Joacer hay 2 ejemplos de como hacerlo, siendo el ejemplo de Pablo la mejor opcion!

Comment: Joacer, voy a ver lo que me has mandado a ver si con esto lo soluciono :). @Cristofer Fuentes, lo que tengo es una notificación push, pero para poder estar recibiendo las notificaciones bien tienes que tener algo funcionando que esté preparado para recibir dichas notificaciones (igual estoy equivocado, es lo que me parece). En el tema de Wasap, yo diría que si que hay un servicio corriendo (si entras en tu dispositivo a la zona de servicios en ejecucion ahí está y como lo cierres ya no te llegan wasap con lo cual deduzco que si que lo hace a través de un servicio)

Comment: Hola @Joacer. He estado mirando un poco el tema del cron (no lo he utilizado hasta ahora) pero no se si es lo que estoy buscando, te explico. Lo primero es que el servicio tiene que estar continuamente funcionando, no cada cierto tiempo, ya que es para controlar unas alarmas y en el momento que surja tiene que avisarme el sistema, no puedo mirar cada cierto tiempo. A ver como lo hago...

Comment: Hola @PabloSimonDiEstefano échale un ojo a la respuesta de JorgeSys que igual se amolda más a lo que necesitas

Comment: SOLUCIONADO!!! La solución ha sido la que me ha dado @Jorgesys, el problema que tenía es que como el servicio recibe datos de la aplicación principal para consultar ciertas cosas, al matarla y reiniciar el servicio no podía recoger esos datos (usuario y pass) y "petaba", así que ahora los recoge desde un fichero y arreglado. Muchas gracias gente!!! :)

Comment: @Mariano, la persona que ha editado esta pregunta. ¿Se puede saber porqué has eliminado el tag de background cuando es lo más importante de la pregunta? El tag background se utiliza para hablar temas relacionados con tareas en segundo plano, ¡exactamente lo que he preguntado! Una cosa es moderar las preguntas y otra quitar tags sin ninguna razón.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano me parece una meta-etiqueta, y el hecho de que tenga dos usos diferentes es un error, y más viendo que se utiliza más frecuentemente para temas de color de fondo. Pero ya que te parece importante, volví a agregaría a la pregunta hasta tanto se defina en [Meta]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si deseas usar un [servicio y este continué ejecutando el proceso aún destruyendo la aplicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/60405/95), debes definir :

> **Service.START_STICKY** : recrea el servicio si la aplicación se
>   destruye.

Puedes ver como ejemplo este servicio que reproduce un archivo de audio:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


/* Add declaration of this service into the AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag*/

public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundSoundService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind()" );
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jorgesys_song);
        player.setLooping(true); 
        player.setVolume(100,100);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service started...");

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUnBind()");
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
    }
    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service stopped...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
    }
}
```

Puedes hacer uso también de un [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: Ha funcionado!!! Muchas gracias @Jorgesys, lo he solucionado con el Service.START_STICKY, no me ha hecho falta el BroadcastReceiver. Un saludo :) y gracias de nuevo

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano excelente, de hecho únicamente con el servicio funciona saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Comment: Pues a mi me deja de funcionar la app cuando la pongo en segundo plano o bien la cierro, me ayudo a medias... Me gustaría saber si podrías ayudarme a dejarla si o si en 2do plano. Muchas gracias igualmente.

Answer (score 1):

**NO uses hilos**

por que estos se mueren al cerrar la app.

**Te recomiendo** utilizar una clase extendida a **Service**

```
    public class ClaseParaEjecutarEnSegundoPlano extends Service {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.i( "msg", "Servicio creado");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intencion, int flags, int idArranque) {
    Log.i( "msg", "Servicio reiniciado");

    //----- Aquí tu codigo--------
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Inicias el servicio desde el Activity

con:

```
    startService(new Intent(this, ClaseParaEjecutarEnSegundoPlano.class));
```

y para detenerlo:

```
    stoptService(new Intent(this, ClaseParaEjecutarEnSegundoPlano.class));
```

Comment: Hola Alfonso, lo primero gracias por la respuesta. Te comento. Me he visto obligado a crear un hilo porque, aunque cree un servicio, tanto en el programa principal como en el hilo secundario (por llamarlo de alguna manera) tengo llamadsa a Asynktask y no se porque no me ejecutaba los 2 a la vez de manera asíncrona, uno me bloqueaba al otro. Al crear un hilo si que me deja ejecutar los 2 asynktask a la vez y no se bloquean