# Control de Actividades

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola tengo el siguiente problema. En una `Activity` tengo un botón que ejecuta un `AsyncTask`. El problema es que si se cierra totalmente la app dicha operación no se ejecuta.

Es posible llamar a un método Asíncrono cuando se cierran aplicaciones? Estuve probando con el método `onDestroy` en mi `Activity` de este modo:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Pero no me muestra el mensaje del Toast al cerrarla. Lo estoy implementado mal? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Espero mi respuesta te ayude :)

Comment: Si te refieres a cerrar la app desde el cajon de aplicaciones o desde ajustes, no va a dispararse el método `onDestroy`. Y tiene que ser así, imagina que ese evento se disparase, podría lanzar la aplicación nuevamente haciendo imposible que se cerrase, esto por ponerte un ejemplo.

Comment: Me podrías ampliar para que quieres hacer un proceso cuando el app se cierra? Te recomiendo levantar un servicio que ejecute la tarea en segundo plano incluso aunque la aplicación se cierre el servicio seguirá ejecutandose. Los async task son útiles para ejecutar procesos fuera del hilo principal de la actividad pero son dependientes igualmente de la actividad por lo que se destruyen con el cierre de la actividad. El método `onDestroy` se ejecuta al destruir la actividad y con ella se van todas las dependencias de la actividad.

Comment: Entiendo a que se refieren con sus respuestas, de hecho tienen mucho sentido. Y bueno seria muy extenso explicar el porque de la necesidad en un comentario pero asi debe ser el comportamiento de la app debido a ciertos inconvenientes con algunos usuarios 'escurridizos'. Con respecto al servicio creo que es la mejor opcion. Gracias.

Comment: @Megaherx te recomiendo revises : https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/crear-un-servicio-en-android

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias! Voy a echarle un ojo para que me quede mas claro todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tu caso parece que necesitas usar `Service`, ya que el AsyncTask se destruye cuando tu aplicación es cerrada si usas el contexto del activity, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

Crear tu clase service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private final LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    protected Handler handler;
    protected Toast mToast;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SendDataService getService() {
            return SendDataService .this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 

                   //realiza tu tarea asíncrona aquí
            }
        });
        return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

Decláralo dentro del AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name="MyService"
    android:label="@string/service_name"
    >
</service>
```

Luego lo inicias:

```
Intent i= new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(i);
```

Para más información te dejo este link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Tengo una consulta, cuando dices que lo inicie vía `Intent` donde deberia hacerlo?

Comment: Desde tu Activity principal por ejemplo , o en el evento que quieres que dispare tu proceso asíncrono.

Comment: @Megaherx si te ayudó mi respuesta, puedes marcarla como resuelta :)

Comment: Si si, se me habia olvidado. Listo!

Answer (score 1):

> Es posible llamar a un método Asíncrono cuando se cierran
>   aplicaciones? Estuve probando con el método onDestroy en mi Activity
>   de este modo:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

> Pero no me muestra el mensaje del Toast al cerrarla. Lo estoy
>   implementado mal? Gracias de antemano.

**Los mensajes `Toast` deben mostrarse sobre un contexto, en el caso de tu código es sobre la `Activity` (`this`), si la aplicación es cerrada, el `Toast` no tendrá una base en donde mostrarse, por ejemplo una Activity.**

Si deseas la ejecución de un método después de cerra una aplicación como opción tienes la de [**crear un servicio**](https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/crear-un-servicio-en-android), el cual puede continuar aún cerrando la aplicación, en este caso definiendo `Service.START_STICKY`

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ...
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

En esta pregunta se encuentra un ejemplo de un servicio que continua en ejecución aún cerrando la aplicación:

[servicios en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60224/servicios-en-android)

En el sitio puedes encontrar actualmente bastante información acerca de los servicios en Android:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+servicio